# Node.js Inheritance

Tags: node.js

I have inherited a class from another JS, and added few prototype function over Parent functions. When i create a new instance of child, i want to call the constructor of parent. Please suggest a way.

> **Parent**

```
function Parent() { .. } 
    Parent.prototype.fn1 = function(){};
    exports.create = function() {
    return (new Parent());
};
```

> **Child**

```
var parent = require('parent');
Child.prototype = frisby.create();
function Child() { .. } 
Child.prototype.fn2 = function(){};
exports.create = function() {
    return (new Child());  
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use module [util](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html). Look simple example:

```
    var util = require('util');

function Parent(foo) {
    console.log('Constructor:  -> foo: ' + foo);
}

Parent.prototype.init = function (bar) {
    console.log('Init: Parent -> bar: ' + bar);
};

function Child(foo) {
    Child.super_.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log('Constructor: Child');
}


util.inherits(Child, Parent);

Child.prototype.init = function () {
     Child.super_.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments); 
     console.log('Init: Child');
};

var ch = new Child('it`s foo!');

ch.init('it`s init!');
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not export create method, export constructor (Child, Parent). Then you will be able to call parent's constructor on child:

```
var c = new Child;
Parent.apply(c);
```

About inheritance. In node you can use `util.inherits` method, which will setup inheritance and setup link to superclass. If you don't need link to superclass or just want to inherit manually, use **proto**:

```
Child.prototype.__proto__ = Parent.prototype;
```

Comment: Problem is, Parent class is from a framework. I dont like to change the source code of a framework. Is there any other way??

Comment: Of course no. There's way around: create instance of parent, create instance of child, and then: `child.constructor.prototype.__proto__ = parent.constructor.prototype`

Answer (score 0):

Parent  (parent.js)

```
function Parent() {
}

Parent.prototype.fn1 = function() {}
exports.Parent = Parent;
```

Child

```
var Parent = require('parent').Parent,
    util = require('util');

function Child() {
   Parent.constructor.apply(this);
}
util.inherits(Child, Parent);

Child.prototype.fn2 = function() {}
```

Comment: Problem is, Parent class is from a framework. I dont like to change the source code of a framework. Is there any other way??